# Can't use VSCode BetterWhitespace ext: "WhiteSpace detected that you set "editor.renderWhitespace" to "selection". The extension will now disabled."

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm trying to use the [BetterWhitespace](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=chmln.better-whitespace) extension with VSCode, but when I install it, [I get a message saying](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nq7fD.png) `WhiteSpace detected that you set "editor.renderWhitespace" to "selection". The extension will now disabled.`

I've tried reinstalling, changing VSCode's default `editor.renderWhitespace` settings to other values such as `all`, and removing that line altogether just to check if that's the source of conflict with this plugin, but none of that has worked so far - I get the same message.

What can I do to get it to work?

The last commit on the extension's repo on GitHub was 4 years ago and the repo is archived, so I couldn't open an issue to ask the author there (I'm hoping this problem is not just because it's out of date). Thanks!

Comment: use setting `none`

Comment: @rioV8 that worked, thanks! Unfortunately though the extension doesn't look as good as expected. There are no spaces between the – characters so it just looks like one continuous line, and there's a very slight but noticeable lag before the characters appear when I select text. Updating in an answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per @riov8's comment, changing the setting to `none` works and the extension is activated. However it doesn't look as expected. While this answers my question of how to get past that error in my OP, the characters don't have any gaps in between so they just look like one continuous line, and there's a very slight but noticeable lag before the characters appear when I select text.

[image: VSCode vs. Sublime Whitespace]

Unless someone knows anything about modifying the extension itself to correct this, I will have to drop it after all.